# Auto generate random alphanumerical characters?

Tags: c#, string, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get random string with spaces and mixed case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683658/how-to-get-random-string-with-spaces-and-mixed-case)

How do I auto generate random alphanumercial characters

```
Valid characters: Uppercase (A-Z), Lowercase (a-z), and digits (0-9)
Size: 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
string def = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
Random rnd = new Random();
StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    ret.Append(def.Substring(rnd.Next(def.Length), 1));
return ret.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
        var possibleChars = new List<char>();
        for(var c='a';c<='z';c++)
        {
            possibleChars.Add(c);
        }
        for (var c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
        {
            possibleChars.Add(c);
        }
        for (var c = '0'; c <= '9'; c++)
        {
            possibleChars.Add(c);
        }
        var r = new Random();
        var randomChar = possibleChars[r.Next(possibleChars.Count)];
```